# What are good resources for research on a particular work?

Tags: theory, history, analysis, learning-resources

Are there some well-known resources for scholars, like JSTOR is for academic papers, or specialized publications?
Any type of investigation on a work is of interest, musical analysis, theory, historical context etc. CD liner notes used to be one of these resources for me. Googling a particular work seldom returns the answers I am looking for. Of course well-known works have books written about them. Wikipedia can be an interesting resource, but again only for famous works (the article for Bach's *Goldberg Variations* for example).
What would be a good place to learn more about, say, Morton Feldman's *Triadic Memories*? Am I missing something or am I stuck with Google and JSTOR?

Comment: I think we do not do resource recommendation in this forum.  See guidelines for more on this.

Comment: Instead of plain google try scholar.google.com or books.google.com just those two should cast a pretty wide research net.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Triadic+Memories%22

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because off-site resource requests are off-topic.